# Load JSON in Ext store, associations missing

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs4.1

I'm using Ext 4.1. I have some issues with loading json data with associations. The flat data gets loaded perfectly, only the 'hasMany' doesn't work. (if loaded there nowhere to be found). If a record is loaded I want to be able to get the 2 stores of Attendee's and the 1 store of documents.

I can also change the JSON format to a better format (if you have suggestions let me know!)

I have [this json data](https://gist.github.com/3377256).

This is my first model:

```
Ext.define('App.model.package.LabVisit', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    requires: [
        'App.model.package.Attendee',
        'App.model.package.Document'
    ],
    idProperty: 'labVisitID',

    fields: [
        {
            mapping: 'lab_visit_id',
            name: 'labVisitID',
            type: 'int'
        },
        {
            mapping: 'lab_id',
            name: 'labID',
            type: 'int'
        },
        ... some more irrelevant...
        {
            mapping: 'comments',
            name: 'comments'
        },
        {
            name: 'upddate'
        }
    ],
    hasMany: [
        /* edit: added foreignKey (also tried with: lab_visit_id) */
        { model: 'package.Attendee', name: 'attendeeLabList', associationKey:'attendee_lab', foreignKey: 'labVisitId' },
        { model: 'package.Attendee', name: 'attendeeEmpList', associationKey:'attendee_emp', foreignKey: 'labVisitId' }
        { model: 'package.Document', name: 'document', associationKey:'document' },
    ]

});
```

I have following attendee model:

```
Ext.define('App.model.package.Attendee', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        /* edit: added this field */
        {
            mapping: 'lab_visit_id',
            name: 'labVisitId'
        },
        {
            mapping: 'attendee_id',
            name: 'AttendeeID'
        },
        {
            mapping: 'first_name',
            name: 'firstName'
        },
        {
            mapping: 'last_name',
            name: 'lastName'
        },
        {
            name: 'email'
        }
    ]
});
```

following document model:

```
Ext.define('App.model.package.Document', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        {
            mapping: 'document_id',
            name: 'docID'
        },
        {
            mapping: 'document_name',
            name: 'docName'
        },
        {
            mapping: 'document_mimetype',
            name: 'mimeType'
        },
        {
            name: 'uploadID'
        }
    ]
});
```

Finally my store:

```
Ext.define('App.store.package.LabVisit', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.JsonStore',
    requires: [
        'App.model.package.LabVisit'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};

        me.callParent([Ext.merge({
            storeId: 'labVisitStore',
            model: 'App.model.package.LabVisit',
            remoteSort: true,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                api: {
                    read: API_URLS.getVisitList //url to the json
                },
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'rows'
                }
            }
        }, cfg)]);
    }
});
```

***Edit:***
I've added the foreign key in the model and added it to the `hasMany`

Still no difference. This is my output:

[image: the first record in the store]

I also find it a strange: If it's broken I expect an exception. And there are 2 mysterious stores always present but I don't have a clue why or what's the purpose.

Comment: I believe that, like many others, you are victim of the confusing nature of associations in ExtJS 4. One clear problem with your code is that the `package.Attendee` model doesn't have a (foreign) key linking it with `package.LabVisit`. If you look at the [docs example](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.association.HasMany), `Product` has `user_id` field to complete the has many association `User` has to it. In other words, your associated model is invalid and wouldn't work regardless the loading.

Comment: @Izhaki I believe I am... That's the thing I'm struggling with from the beginning. So you say it will (only) work when I add a `belongsTo` and add a `labVisit_id` to the `package.Attendee` model...

Comment: No, you don't need the `belongsTo`, you just need `labVisit_id` in the `package.Attendee` model. But that raises the question whether an Attendee can only be in one labVisit - it seems to me that There's a list of people and you are trying to associated them with labvisits. So a many-to-many might be the way to go here, but it's not part of ExtJS although can be easily implemented using an association store.

Comment: @Izhaki Theoretically you're right but this is coming from the backend I just want a store with childstores. The many to many is overkill. But I can't get my head around the association stuff in ExtJS 4.x. I've also tried using a converter returning the child store. Not the best solution but I really need to get it working.

Comment: I strongly believe that you'll find the answer to your question in the `nested-loading` example (/examples/app/nested-loading). Also have a look at the sibling `feed-viewr`.

Comment: Just so I stand corrected - it turns out you don't have to define user_id; I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Izhaki/K7U7V/1/) of some docs code and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in this part:

```
hasMany: [
    { model: 'package.Attendee', name: 'attendeeLabList', associationKey:'attendee_lab' },
    { model: 'package.Attendee', name: 'attendeeEmpList', associationKey:'attendee_emp' },
    { model: 'package.Document', name: 'document', associationKey:'document' },
]
```

@Izhaki helped me a lot. Thanx! Especially with the fiddle. I started there and begun with switching the code with my code piece by piece. Until I saw the model was the problem.

models should be defined like this:  `App.model.package.Attendee`

I think it's sad that the framework doesn't show a significant error/warning if a model isn't recognised/doesn't excist/isn't supplied... But meh, it works now.